# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.tensor'

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, tensor

How to solve this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arulsuju/Desktop/OfflineSignatureVerification-master/OfflineSignatureVerification-master/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Preprocessing import convert_to_image_tensor, invert_image
  File "C:\Users\arulsuju\Desktop\OfflineSignatureVerification-master\OfflineSignatureVerification-master\Preprocessing.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torch.tensor import Tensor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.tensor'
```

in Python I am using

```py
from torch.tensor import Tensor
```

Answer (score 5):

In line 4, change this

```
 from torch.tensor import Tensor
```

TO

```
 from torch import Tensor
```